# Make winXP live USB or at least bootable USB from OpenSuse to play Diablo 3 from that USB

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, opensuse, bootloader

I bought Diablo 3 (windows and Mac game) and I want to play it on my notebook, but I have only OpenSuse installed on it and I can't dual boot, because I can't backup the files and have the maximum amount of partitions, so the only way to dual boot was to make an extended partition and install XP on part of it, but I think it's quite hardcore change to the partitions, so there's possible huge lose of my installed system and/or data (am I right?).

I also tried Wine to install Diablo, but despite that they say it's installable on OpenSuse with Wine, it isn't.. it starts endless loop during install. I also tried to install it through VirtualMachine and copy the folder to OpenSuse and run it with wine from here, but it also doesn't work with many kinds of errors I can't fix. I also tried playing D3 through playonlinux, but I get some errors with old python 2.6 (I have already newer python, but maybe there's some broken compatibility.. I don't know).

So I thought that I just install winXP on my flashdisc and will play it from it, so I used another flashdisc for install, I formatted it with gparted to fat32 and used unetbootin to make an bootable install USB of winXP from it, then I restarted PC and chose to boot from it, then I see some menu and countdown from 10 seconds and the seconds are going to 0, then the timer restarts. There is also an opinion "default" in the menu and when I choose it, the timer also restarts.

So how to fix it? And can I install the winXP from this flashdisc on another flashdisc, if I fix it? And then can I boot XP from that disc or there is a different way to make a bootable live winXP USB device? And when I change partition with enough free space from non-extended to extended in gparted, how much possible is that i lose any data from that partition?

And if I won't solve any of these problems, can I go to shop, buy external HDD and somehow install winXP on it and use it like normal HDD to play Diablo 3 from it? Making the Diablo playable on this notebook is so painful to me...

Comment: Have you also tried with *PlayOnLinux* instead of *Wine* (only)?

Comment: Yes and I get errors with Python 2.6 libraries, I reinstalled them and  I still have those errors.

Comment: Am I just extremely unlucky to play Diablo? So many solutions and no1 working for me :(

Comment: I was trying to fix every error and the only thing what happened is that I am half-insane now.

Comment: Just a side note, back up your data... it sounds like you never did. You can't trust your hardware to never break nor expect the software to be bug-free.

Comment: This question is rambling and difficult to follow. Apparently, you tried several methods but failed each time. Instead of providing a summary of the story of your life, ask a focused question (or several) concerning a specific difficulty you encountered. For example, changing partitions is not so difficult, but we can't help you without knowing what partitions you currently have (e.g. the output of `fdisk -l` under Linux). We can't help with your Python errors without having the error messages. And so on.

Comment: Have you tried just installing VirtualBox or another VM solution and play Diablo3 from within that?

Comment: OK, my co-workers fixed it for me somehow to play it through wine. @jcolebrand I have installed VirtualBox, but it doesn't support GPUs, so I couldn't play it without graphic card...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Windows XP installation cd you can create a bootable USB stick that will run some kind of Windows environment.

This can be done with a windows app called [PEBuilder](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), not sure if it runs under wine but it will sure work under virtualbox.

You might also try to google for a ready-made BartPE ISO which you can then install to a usb stick.

PEBuilder has a plugin system so you might actually get DirectX working and maybe even include video drivers but all this does not guarantee that the game will run, typically most apps need specific 'plugins' in order to run under BartPE and most games probably won't work with proper 3D acceleration and correct video drivers.

All that said, I would rather recommend to non-destructively resize your hdd partitions (using Partition Magic, Paragon Hard Disk Manager, or [free alternatives](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-partition-manager.htm)) and make enough space for installing a real win32 system.